# I have to write a JS program to solve a 4x5 grid puzzle . how to I write code to construct a tree with all possible moves?

Tags: data-structures

Here is the link to the puzzle: http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/ZPAGES/zzzQuzzle.html

My idea is to construct the tree of all possible moves and then use a search algorithm (probably BFS or A*) to find the shortest path to the solution.

This is the initial state:

> 1 1 2 2 
>   1 1 3 4 
>   0 0 3 4 
>   5 6 6 7 
>   5 8 8 9

This is the final state (mirror of the start state):

> 2 2 1 1 
>   4 3 1 1 
>   4 3 0 0 
>   7 6 6 5 
>   9 8 8 5

I need help to figure out how to construct the tree of possible states from the start state. Only sliding vertically and horizontally is allowed. no rotations)

Comment: It's easiest if you write a program for that. Generate all possible positions, then for each position, find all positions you can reach from there.

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here.